# Haskell - constructing a type that uses existential quantification

Tags: haskell, existential-type

In the code below I have defined a data type F using existential quantification. I would like values of type F to hold functions that accept a single argument and produce, say, an Int as the result. The argument needs to implement a type class which I've called C, but left empty for now.

This is my first attempt at existential types. I am clearly doing something wrong as I don't seem to be able to create values of type F.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class C a where

data F = forall a. C a => F (a->Int)

makeF :: F
makeF = F $ const 1
```

How can I fix this compile error?

```
No instance for (C a0) arising from a use of `F'
In the expression: F
In the expression: F $ const 1
In an equation for `makeF': makeF = F $ const 1
```

Comment: I find that this sort of thing is easier to do with a GADT. You can have the existential quantification and the class constraint, but the syntax is so much cleaner and easier.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I should really read up on GADTs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite your `F` definition as below it will work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

class C a where

data F = F (forall a. C a => a -> Int)

makeF :: F
makeF = F $ const 1
```

I'm trying to understand why myself:

Your original type says "there exists `a` which is instance of `C`, and we have function `a -> Int`".
So to construct existential type, we have to state which `a` we have:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class C a where

data F = forall a. C a => F (a -> Int)

-- Implement class for Unit
instance C () where

makeF :: F
makeF = F $ (const 1 :: () -> Int)
```

---

These aren't exactly equivalent definitions:

```
data G = forall a . C a => G {
  value :: a         -- is a value! could be e.g. `1` or `()`
  toInt :: a -> Int, -- Might be `id`
}

data G' = G' {
  value' :: C a => a          -- will be something for every type of instance `C`
  toInt' :: C a => a -> Int, -- again, by parametericity uses only `C` stuff
}
```

Comment: Great, my code now compiles :) And thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I amended the answer a bit. There is slight difference between `RankNType` and `ExistentialQuantification` approach.

Comment: The two versions are not slightly different, they are very different.  In one the variable is universally quantified in the other existentially.  It makes a huge difference to how you can use the function.

Comment: @augustss, Do you have a use case in mind, where one approach works and other is almost impossible? E.g. for [24 days of GHC extensions](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-19-existential-quantification.html) example both approaches would work equally well?

Comment: @Oleg I'm on my phone so my reply will be short.  With universal quantification, after pattern matching you can use the function with a type of your choice (many different, if you want).  With existential quantification, after pattern matching the type variable has a fixed type, but you don't know which one; it behaves as an abstract type.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `const 1` has type `forall a . C a => a -> Int`. When you pass that to `F` we lose the opportunity to ever talk about the type `a` again excepting that it is an element of type `C`.

Unfortunately, we've never determined what `a` must be!

In particular, GHC handles existentials like this by passing in the *dictionary* for the typeclass C corresponding to whatever type actually ends up in the existential. Since we never provided GHC enough information to find that dictionary it gives us a type error.

So to fix this we must instantiate `C` somewhere

```
instance C Int
```

and then pass a function which determines that the forgotten type `a` actually is an instance of `C`

```
let x = F (const 1 :: Int -> Int)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This gives me a more intuitive feel for what is going on. It seems that Existential Types aren't really what I want here. I need to be able to compose my F's to create new F's without knowing what the concrete type that implements C is.

Comment: @knick Is it important that the compiler doesn't know what the concrete type is? I ask in case your usage scenario can do with polymorphism rather than existential types.